# .mtl file not found error in obj to js file conversion

Tags: javascript, python, three.js

I have [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/converters/obj/convert_obj_three.py)
python script to convert .obj file to .json file.I have i tried to convert messi.obj to messi.js using this script. then this script print

```
couldn'find messi.mtl file
```

on console. Why `.mtl` file need to convert obj to js. is it possible to do this conversion without .mtl file?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to open your obj-File with a text editor and remove the mtl library reference line if there is one?